# Where do you find solar panels to make the solar flare in Mafia Wars?

Tags: mafia-wars

I can never find solar panels in jobs/fights/robbing. My chop shop is a high enough level to make the "Solar Flare", but I just can't find the parts.

Where are these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They drop randomly from doing jobs and fighting in New York. Presumably, the rate is similar to any other Chop Shop item, as there are not exceptions noted, but I personally haven't fought or done jobs in NY at all really since the Chop Shop was introduced, so I'm not entirely sure.
~[Source](http://mafiawars.wikia.com/wiki/Solar_Panel)